# Javafx and Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx, platform

I develop a project in java and I have some components already written in swing. I am planning to continue with JavaFX but one of these Swing components can not be ported into javaFX. So, I heard that Netbeans platform can be used to work with Swing and JavaFx together but I could not find any good sources.

Is there any way to develop netbeans modules that some of them written in javaFx and some of them in Swing?

Comment: See [Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm).  (Top link for the magic words of 'embed swing java-fx'.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AndrewThompson, but I have already tried that. I do not want to "embed" swing into javafx, I want to have swing and javafx components side by side without embedding. I heard that Netbeans platform can do that by creating modules. one module can be in Swing and other in JavaFx.

Comment: No, they can't, Swing and JavaFX have different rendering pipelines and event models, they aren't compatible in that way, you'd have to embed them as Andrew has pointed out.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm